# Does a question about making a "best" choice become okay just because it is "popular"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33761351/1) is clearly **off-topic** and **too-broad** as well as being a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159797/when-should-i-use-iterable-vs-collection-in-java) at the same time, even after the edit to snarkily remove the word *best*; but just because they want to have a discussion about the merits of what they want to do it is okay. Same thing with a 1 rep user and the question would have been closed in just a couple of minutes.

> I think the close/reopen war that is going on with the original
> question is kind of proof that it was a bad question. That with the
> *got what I wanted* answer ( now deleted ) below kind of proves out why `too-broad` + `opinion based` is bad for the site.

The most recent edits do not make it any less broad or opinion based.

#### Once the question in question was closed and deleted by 5 votes I deleted this because I did not think it added any value anymore.

I changed the title because nature took it's core and it was artificially reversed.

The unilateral undeleting of this and the question it references because of the logical fallacy of [Argumentum_ad_populum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) after popular consent closed and deleted both multiple times brings to question the wisdom of interfering with something that worked itself out.

Comment: Why don't  you mark it as too broad if you feel that it is?

Comment: I don't see any indication that the poster's rep enters into this at all.

Comment: Well, there are 3 close votes already given by now? What's your problem? You want to place a downvote!/close vote, what's hindering you actually? We see robo upvotes on high rep user questions all day long, reviewers are stupid most of the time, and don't always judge by content quality.

Comment: @ventsyv, pantarei, Jarrod [has already voted to close once](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33761351/revisions) and cannot do so again.

Comment: I would change the title of this question to "So why is that **some** high rep users think they can... blah blah" Cause otherwise you're generalizing.

Comment: This looks like you're just trying to exploit the Meta-effect by framing a specific question as a general problem.

Comment: _@Jarrod Roberson_ Why did you actually apply the [tag:duplicate-questions] tag here? If it's relevant, did you close vote that question as a duplicate?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Jarrod actually dupehammered the question in question. (See the link from Josh Caswell's comment.)

Comment: @Kendra So what's the point asking here then?

Comment: So you dupe-hammered it, someone else with a gold badge didn't think it deserved that. So we have 2 users involved so far. Couldn't you have settled that amongst yourself within the tag? Or within a topic related chat?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As Bill the Lizard said, it looks like a meta-effect call to me. I was just pointing out, as did Josh earlier, that Jarrod _did_ already vote to close, and _did_ have the question closed. It was un-dupehammered by another gold badge user.

Comment: @Kendra I prefer operating on the question itself, instead of calling for the _meta effect_, but we'll that's my opinion.

Comment: Seeing how Paul Boddington was the first voter to close as "primarily opinion based", perhaps he merely thought that was a better close reason than a dupe?

Comment: In my experiences this is not at all unexpected, but has nothing to do with the rep of the author.  People love discussing these extremely broad and opinion based questions, and over time it's gotten notably harder to actually get them closed.  There are enough people ([example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310492/1159478)) that just want to entertain themselves debating topics out of SO's scope, and enough of them have the reopen privilege to mean that these questions are often not closed or quickly reopened.

Comment: @Servy _has nothing to do with the rep of the author_ but _enough of them have the reopen privilege_. With higher rep, you can allow yourself to do these things. And users trust that you know what you're doing when you have that `k` in your reputation. They're doing more harm than lower reputation users would have.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see enough questions like this either not get closed, get reopened, and with a positive score to feel pretty confident in saying that the problem here isn't the rep of the author.  People keep voting to reopen and upvote these kinds of questions even when 1 rep users post them.  They're entertaining, and that's enough for lots of people.

Comment: @Servy Is it a _bigger_ problem with high rep in your opinion?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not notably.  How the question is treated by the community is far more important for the impressions of future readers than the rep of the author.  If the question would be closed, downvoted, not answered, and not reopened, then I think the message that such questions don't belong here would be seen pretty strongly by readers, regardless of how much rep the author has.

Comment: @Servy "over time it's gotten notably harder to actually get them closed". This is completely the reverse of reality. So many people are eager to pounce on the "too broad" / "primarily opinion-based" button nowadays, closing good questions just to let themselves feel useful. This afternoon I saw [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755521) closed as "opinion-based" for some bizarre reason. It was actually [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/) anyway so doesn't matter, but my point is, the original would never have been let live had it been asked today.

Comment: @Boann The fact that a question is *also* a duplicate doesn't mean that it's *not* opinion based or too broad.  The fact that you like discussing opinions and having extremely broad questions doesn't mean that they're actually good for the site; them often people popular doesn't mean that they're actually useful quality questions.

Comment: @Servy That question isn't opinion-based or too broad. It asks what the practical difference between `for (;;)` and `while (true)` is that would give reason to choose one over the other. That's a perfectly objective question. The accepted answer shows that which loop form to use turns out to be a matter of preference, but the question itself isn't asking about preferences.

Comment: @Boann No, that's *not* what the question is asking.  The question asserts, as a premise, that the two are the same, and asks why a developer would choose one over the other.  The question *isn't* unaware that it's purely personal preference.

Comment: @Servy "Is there a difference at compilation time?" and "Is for(;;) faster?" are perfectly objective questions. You don't need to be afraid of them.  There are potentially plenty other non-preference based reasons why a developer would choose one over the other; maybe one causes problems in some scenarios. There's nothing wrong with asking about that.

Comment: @Boann That's not what the question is asking though.  That's the problem with very broad and opinion based questions.  Everyone just interprets them as being about the thing *they* care about, but it's *not* just about that.  You can ask a specific, focused, objective question related to some of these topics, but that's not what that question is doing.  Additionally asking, "explain all of the differences" is virtually always too broad.  You'd need to be asking about a specific difference.

Comment: @Boann - your arguing with Servy is the perfect example why these questions are problematic. And for the record Servy is correct, what you are arguing about is too-broad and opinion-based and micro-benchmarking is pretty much off-topic for a bunch of other reasons as well.

Comment: Could you at least be consistent? If you want to close my question (and someone even wants to delete it), shouldn't the one you cited be closed as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159797/when-should-i-use-iterable-vs-collection-in-java

Comment: I don't understand the edit; the question **isn't** popular, unless you consider -4 with 250 views "popular" -- I don't. What's more, the question "is it OK to keep a bad question open because it's popular" was answered long, long ago, and resoundingly and universally in the negative. The question *was* asked by a high-rep user, and you could maybe try to double down on some perceived inconsistency in handling because of that (not that you'll get very far without a really thoroughly irenic tone, but eh), but popularity is a red herring.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - a moderator unilaterally undeleted and reopened the question and THIS one with the sole reasoning that it was their opinion that the question was popular and therefore useful. See the answer below.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: (1) I cast the *third* undelete vote. Any 20k+ user could have done the same. (2) No moderator has touched THIS question except when Shog9 added a tag. (3) Popularity was not my argument. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the question is both too broad and opinion-based.

Too broad because a good answer would need to first include a copy-paste of the *very long* documentation of all the classes involved, then move on the pointing out the differences, then move on to saying when you should use one over the other.

Opinion-based because when you will have made all that hard work, you'll realize that the crucial part of the answer will come down to a "I would do it like this". Some actually enjoy questions like that; but the point is, such questions are off-topic.

The question should be closed as such.

Now this raises another consideration: behaviour among gold badge holders of a tag. We are talking about the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag here, which has currently 354 gold badge holders. That's a lot. Actually, [that's the second "best"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/393943/504930/), the first being [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). With such a high amount of gold badge holders, disagreement is bound to happen.

Honestly, I don't think you should have raised this issue, like this, on Meta: no offense, but your post reads like a rant and doesn't really ask a question. You should have taken this matter to chat, between you, who voted to close, and the individual who voted to reopen. Note that you could also have invited other gold badge holders: while writing this, I'm thinking that maybe it would be a good idea to create a special chat room for gold badge holders to discuss about such matters (this is just an idea).

---

In your post, there is also the matter of reputation. I don't think this is a problem: I feel this question would have been treated the same way if it had been posted by a new user. A post by a high-rep user tends, maybe, to attract a couple more of upvotes from users (making the assumption that high-rep = good knowledge on the subject). But, in the end, you still would have voted to close, the other user would still have voted to reopen, and exactly the same actions would have taken place. The difference would just have been the *score* of the question, not its open / close status.

Comment: I like your answer but saying *" the other user would still have voted to reopen"* its a vague assumption of something you're not sure is going to happen, unless you can see the future. Other than that I completely agree with you.

Comment: There are scores of questions concerning the types of *parameters*, most of which manage to summarize the **relevant** differences in a few sentences; I'm not sure why return type would require slavish quotation of the entire class documentation. The essential question is roughly, "is it better to return a more or less generic type?" which should be possible to address without delving into the minutia of the types themselves.

Comment: @Shog9 At that point you're removing everything objective about the question and turning it back into its first revision which is primarily opinion based.  You're just asking people to tell you what they prefer to, rather than explaining how the things are different.  It's exactly the kind of question that primarily opinion based is there to prevent.

Comment: I read the first revision, @Servy: the form is exactly as I summarized, but even then it was considerably more specific... And it's only become more focused since then. So again, we have plenty of specific questions that take this form WRT parameters and somehow manage to avoid degenerating into opinionated nonsense... But a return value is gonna be a poll? I'm skeptical; honestly, I'm having trouble grasping the real concern here, since there's precious little evidence to back up the problems that've been tossed out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the problem with it; it's *not* particularly broad, and seems like the sort of question that could be beneficial for folks learning to write effective Java.

[mmyers already did a pretty thorough analysis of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310488/does-a-question-about-making-a-best-choice-become-okay-just-because-it-is-pop/310572#310572), but I feel compelled to add a reference to [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), which drew on [Aarobot's essay on Poll questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/should-polls-be-maintained-as-community-wiki-questions-or-should-they-be-closed/75179#75179) to arrive at the guidance that currently lives in the help center under "Don't Ask". The essence of both is simple: a question must reflect an honest effort to solve a real problem existing within the topic scope of the site.

**This is my opinion on the question you've brought here**:

- Designing an API is a real problem
- Choosing a return type has real implications for how the method can be used in the future
- Those implications can be enumerated, their costs and advantages weighed, examples produced to illustrate them, all within a reasonably-sized answer

Thus, the question is not inherently too broad nor too subjective. (I'm not sure where you're getting off-topic)

You might be right about duplicates though. Not the one you identified, mind you - but there are others that come closer. For instance:

- [Is it bad practice to return an iterable in a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474862/is-it-bad-practice-to-return-an-iterable-in-a-method)
- [collection vs list vs arrays as return type for EJB method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667903/collection-vs-list-vs-arrays-as-return-type-for-ejb-method)

Which leaves open the question: which one of these questions best represents the problem being solved? Which one should we use as the dup-target?

Comment: `Those implications can be enumerated, their costs and advantages weighed, examples produced to illustrate them, all within a reasonably-sized answer`  That's the problem though, the answer just picks one or two implications to discuss, and there are *always* more to discuss.  The accepted answer only really brings up like two facets of the decision.  I can think of half a dozen more off of the top of my head, and I imagine that others could come up with still more.  If the question limits the scope of comparison between the options to a particular facet, that's different.

Comment: Discussion can be useful, but shouldn't be the goal of any SO question, @Servy. Are there other factors not covered by the existing answer? Sure. Are they important? Perhaps. Are they likely to be important *and* remain unaddressed? Doubtful - particularly if we consolidate some duplicates here.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is a loaded question. Let me try to separate your series of questions out and address them individually.

**Does it make a difference whether a question is asked by a high rep user?** Well, yes, it could. Since the reputation count is displayed right there by the user name, it's not hard to be subconsciously influenced by it. This is [not a new problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/should-there-be-anonymous-answers-and-questions).

**Would this question have been closed in a couple of minutes if it were asked by a 1-rep user?** Yes, it only stayed open 13 minutes and I don't imagine it would have survived any longer if it were asked by a 1-rep user.

**Should this question have been closed?** Here's the question you didn't ask. You used your hammer to close the linked question and someone else used theirs to reopen it. How could anyone possibly reopen a question that's clearly off topic, too broad, and a duplicate?

For starters, it's not a duplicate. I've edited the title of [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159797/when-should-i-accept-a-parameter-of-iterablet-vs-collectiont-in-java) to make that clearer. But isn't it still subjective and off-topic?

Let's take a quick trip to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, *avoid* asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

None of these apply to the linked question.

> **Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be *constructive*.** What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Huh. This question already inspired a long answer that explains "why".

---

Our basic rules for questions are:

1. Does it meet our topic requirements?
2. Does it make the internet a better place?

Both this question and [the linked non-duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159797/when-should-i-accept-a-parameter-of-iterablet-vs-collectiont-in-java) meet the topic requirements. The other question has 12000 views and 39 upvotes; to me, that means it's making the internet better. I want to give this question a chance to do the same.

I have undeleted and reopened the question.

Comment: You didn't explain why the question isn't too broad.

Comment: `How could anyone possibly reopen a question that's clearly off topic, too broad, and a duplicate?`  Well, considering someone [already posted an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310492/1159478) about this exact question just to say that they didn't *care* whether the question is close worthy or not, they're going to do what they want because they can (and that person has reopen privileges) I think it's pretty clear that people can and do vote to reopen questions that merit closure.

Comment: Views and upvotes are just signs that the post is *popular*.  One of the core problems with highly subjective questions, and also extremely broad questions, is that they're so often *very* popular *even though they're not useful*.  People love to share their opinions, see the opinions of others, provide some little chunk of an answer to an *extremely* broad question, etc.  It's *fun*, so lots of people participate, and they upvote each other's content. That doesn't that the content is useful.  Those two close reasons exist precisely because this content is so popular, despite not being useful.

Comment: _"How could anyone possibly reopen a question that's clearly off topic, too broad, and a duplicate?"_ To be completely fair, the user that reopened it _then_ voted to close it as opinion based. So it's clear to me that that user thought it wasn't a duplicate but _was_ opinion based. (Continuing to be completely fair, that vote may have been before the edit to the question and I don't see that user having weighed in either here or there, so he could think it's fine now.)

Comment: @Servy (1st comment): Good answers are not too long for this format, which I can show by pointing to the existing answer. And the burden of proof, such as it is, is on the closers.

Comment: @Servy (3rd comment): Yes. You're reiterating what the help center says and I quoted.

Comment: @Kendra and Servy (2nd comment): Apparently I needed to use a [rhetorical question mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Rhetorical_question_mark).

Comment: @MichaelMyers The fact that a question has answers doesn't mean its not too broad.  People love to answer questions that are too broad, they just don't provide complete answers.  They provide some little bit of information on the subject, or skim the surface of what a proper answer would be, rather than actually posting a complete answer (since a complete answer wouldn't be possible/practical).  As for closers supporting their position, there's tons all over this meta question.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Your rhetorical question is insinuating an answer; one that is pretty clearly not the case.  Phrasing it as a question doesn't mean that I can't point out why it's a flawed insinuation.

Comment: @MichaelMyers You asserted that the question is useful because it has views and upvotes.  I'm stating that views and upvotes don't mean that it's necessarily useful.  It's literally the opposite of what you're claiming in your answer.

Comment: @Servy, you put words in my mouth. "someone already posted an answer about this exact question just to say that they didn't care whether the question is close worthy or not, they're going to do what they want " I in no way did that. I care whether it is close worthy. What I do not care is to spend effort trying to meet artificially strict rules just to make the site's curation-obsessed members happy. I will do what I feel is a reasonable effort to put together a question. I will not bend over backwards to meet unreasonable standards.

Comment: @MichaelMyers -- thanks for taking a closer look at the question objectively.

Comment: this answer is **not objective**, it is opinion that *popular == useful* presented as *"fair and balanced"* which is a [logical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) of the worst kind.

Comment: Also, off-topic != not useful. In the same way that being useful doesn't make something on-topic, being off-topic doesn't make it not useful either. Whether y'all believe there's a balance to be struck between the two otherwise completely orthogonal virtues is another story. (Judging by the comments, though, it seems to be a black-and-white matter.)

Answer (score -23):

Do what you want.

I got the help I was looking for, and if all you care about is curating this site content to be perfect, go ahead. It just alienates potential contributors (and I used to be a fairly active one).

---

edit: I believe there are reasonable compromises between focusing on long-term "perfection" of content and keeping "noise" down, and respecting the original authors' (both Q and A) intents and the original questioner's need for a solution. Over the last 7 years I have seen more and more focus on the former and less focus on the latter. It's definitely affecting my attitude and participation on this site. I no longer care much about how you treat me, but it does bother me that other people have been hurt, and that SO has sacrificed a good chunk of its welcomeness in the pursuit of "quality". So please don't forget that, when you get annoyed that people don't follow all the rules to the letter and feel the need to take action.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Comment: this is the kind of attitude that prompted me to post this, appears I was correct in my assessment of entitlement. Thanks for confirming it personally.

Comment: _"I got the help I was looking for"_ Fundamentally wrong approach to the site. We're hunting help vampires out! Do you prefer wooden poles, silver bullets or lifting the curtains tommorow morning?

Comment: Geez people, will you guys just stop it with the pissing contest and go and figure out a solution?

Comment: entitlement, no. Help vampire, no. My statement is merely a reaction against the over-focus of SO on curation and strict adhererence to rules. But that's ok, you do what you want.

Comment: @Bart -- thanks, I haven't heard enough of that attitude on this site in a long time. Still gives me some hope.

Comment: @JasonS It's not really an _attitude_, but merely a main goal and stated clearly in the site policies. If you're still confusing Stack Overflow with being your personal help-desk, sorry to say you're on the wrong track.

Comment: ...and it's my contention that SO is on the wrong track. But whatever.

Comment: Well, you are welcome to ask for the scope of the site to be changed. Though you should be precise about how and how far it should be changed, and you should provide really strong arguments for, as well as a close and thorough look at any potential harm that might cause. Attacking those enforcing the current consensus as pedantic bean-counters or some such (even if it should be true ;-)) won't help convince anyone . Also, such should be done on meta, not by just breaking it on main.

Comment: ITT: people getting triggered by the word "help". Apparently such is taboo now on a site whose *goal* (as someone put it), ironically, has always been about providing solutions to programming problems. But perhaps I misremembered.